# How can I fix my layout location bugs?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Hi guys I'm new on android and I have some problems with my layout. What I wanna do is to place the bar with the button in the end of my popup window. This is the situation without descriptions:

[image: without descriptions]

And if there is some rows of description, this is what it happens:

[image: With description]

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="4050dp"
    android:minHeight="4050dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:textSize="10pt"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/snippet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:textSize="8pt"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|fill_horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/telephone_icon"
            android:id="@+id/telephone_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#f5f5f5"/>


        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/email_icon"
            android:id="@+id/email_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#f5f5f5"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titolo_descrizione"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Descrizione"/>

        <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/testo_descrizione"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:textSize="8pt"
                android:textStyle="italic"/>
        </ScrollView>




    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/email_icon"
            android:id="@+id/get_direction_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#f5f5f5"/>
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for every suggestions!

Comment: ... MUSSOLINI?!!! WTF!!!

Comment: For that layout set `layout_gravity = "bottom"` and if it doesn't work then add weights to your elements.

Also make sure that it's parent has `layout_height = "match_parent"`.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I'm developing an app for the birthcity of Mussolini, with Historical POI and other POI

Comment: I would never accept this job.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein it's like any another city app...nothing on my app is Pro-Mussolini

Comment: Would you also accept a job on Hitler's birth city?

Comment: My boss live there...is only a city...Mussolini born there and there is some historical POI ... so you wouldn't accept a job on Rome because in the Colosseum people fun themselves watching other people eaten by tigers and lions?

Comment: OK, let's stop it. I could have an anaphylactic shock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this by your xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="4050dp"
android:minHeight="4050dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id= "@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

<LinearLayout
        android:id= "@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/snippet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:textSize="8pt"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id= "@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|fill_horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/telephone_icon"
        android:id="@+id/telephone_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f5f5f5"/>


    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/email_icon"
        android:id="@+id/email_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f5f5f5"/>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id= "@+id/LinearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titolo_descrizione"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Descrizione"/>

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/testo_descrizione"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:textStyle="italic"/>
    </ScrollView>




</LinearLayout>

<RadioGroup
    android:id= "@+id/RadioGroup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:alignparentBottom = "true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/email_icon"
        android:id="@+id/get_direction_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f5f5f5"/>
</RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have changed this with your code only so please change the id name according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout and set `android:alignParentBottom="true"` for your ImageButton

Comment: I try now :) and I will say to you

Comment: With android:alignParentBottom="true" it gaves me error:

Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'alignParentBottom' in package 
  'android'

Comment: change your root layout to relative layout and place your linear layout inside this layout

Comment: consider a study on this topic   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Relative_Layout_Basics_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=73&aaid=97